# How to trigger build from branch specifications?

Tags: teamcity, git-flow, teamcity-9.0

In my teamcity build configuration:

VCS branch: `master`

VCS branch specification:

```
+:refs/heads/hotfix/(*)
+:refs/heads/(master)
```

VCS trigger:

Quiet period: `60 seconds (default)`

Branch filter:

```
+:*
-:<default>
```

And trigger run build only if has changes in master. Tf there are changes in other VCS branches (in branch specification), TeamCity shows "Pending (N)", but the trigger does not start the build.

How to make a run TeamCity build? I have used different ways of specifying brunch filters, does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you defined in Default branch under VCS settings? It should be master. Actually if you need to trigger builds for all branches as per your branch specification, I think you don't need to specify anything in branch filter. It by default takes everything. So try after removing branch filter.

Comment: Even If i takes everything, trigger build not run, does not matter :(

Comment: Branch filter: -:<default>